# Wixsharp custom ManagedUI after bootstrapper bundle install prerequisites

Tags: wix, setup-project, wixsharp

I want to install prerequisites and then display custom UI, with ManagedUI. So far I noticed that doesn't work. It works if I use Wix prebuild UI (WixUI_FeatureTree) but not with ManagedUI. I have bootstrapped bundle that installs .Net Framework 4.8 and C++ redistributables, and after that I want to display UI of my msi. Is there a way to make that work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately using a combination of a ManagedUI and the default Bundle bootstrapper is not possible due to an underlying Wix v3.x [issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4921/). Wix Burn, which is used to create the bootstrapper bundle, doesn't support the WiX EmbeddedUI concept. The Wix team has acknowledged this and does not plan to correct this in the 3.x version.

An alternative is to use the NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) bootstrapper as an alternative to the Wix Burn bootstrapper. See [NsisBootstrapper](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/master/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/Bootstrapper/NsisBootstrapper/setup.cs) sample.

See:

- [Support for msi package EmbeddedUI #4921](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4921/)
- [Custom UI with bundled Bootstrapper #793](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/issues/793)